# Java use void method for stream mapping?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a void method that just does transformation on an object, without returning any value, and I want to use it in a context of a stream map() function, like this:

```
public List<MyObject> getList(){
    List<MyObject> objList = ...
    return objList.stream().map(e -> transform(e, e.getUuid())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private void transform(MyObject obj, String value){
    obj.setUuid("prefix" + value);
}
```

The example is made up for simplicity - the actual method is doing something else than just mucking up the UUID of an object.

Anyway, how is that possible to use a void method in a scenario like the above?
Surely, I could make the method return the transformed object, but that's besides the point and is violating the design (the method should be void).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Seems like this is a case of forced usage of java 8 stream. Instead you can achieve it with forEach.

```
List<MyObject> objList = ...
objList.forEach(e -> transform(e, e.getUuid()));
return objList;
```

Answer (score 15):

In addition to [Eugene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41719942/4105457) you could use `Stream::map` like this:

```
objList.stream()
   .map(e -> {
      transform(e, e.getUuid()); 
      return e;
   }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Actually, you don't want to transform your current elements and collect it into a new `List`.

Instead, you want to apply a method for each entry in your `List`.

Therefore you should use `Collection::forEach` and return the `List`.

```
List<MyObject> objList = ...;
objList.forEach(e -> transform(e, e.getUuid()));
return objList;
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are sure that this is what you want to do, then use **peek** instead of map

Comment: This is not a good method as the design of peek is for debugging purposes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: Apologies for a late response: Additionally, because peek is intended for debugging, the JRE is free to skip calls to peek altogether. https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3864

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `peek(Consumer<? super T> action)` method. It takes a consumer as a parameter, performs an action on each of the elements and returns a stream.

```
objList.stream().peek(e -> transform(e,e.getUuid())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: According to the documentation, peek() is unreliable and should only be used for debugging. Sonarlint with default settings will report this as a major issue. Also, your answer is literally the same as the one form Eugene.